# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking - Multiple Accounts

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

We are using Google Analytics on hundreds of client sites. Each site has its own account, and we also have an account for aggregate data. We're using the following code for tracking pageviews to both accounts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);  //obviously fake UA numbers
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(
['aggregate._setAccount', 'UA-87654321-1'],
['aggregate._trackPageview']
);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =         true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

This is working well for tracking visits & behaviour, but I'm not sure how to implement the same type of double tracking for the ecommerce tracking code. We're using the usual _addTrans, _addItem and _trackTrans setup.

How can I adapt the ecommerce tracking to report to both accounts?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `aggregate.` in the `_gaq.push` calls like `aggregate._setAccount` is used to create an additional named tracker.

Just copy the ecommerce `_gaq.push` code lines, and add `aggregate.` in front of the `_addTrans`, `_addItem` and `_trackTrans` calls.

For example,

```
 _gaq.push(['_addTrans', ...parameters...]);
 _gaq.push(['aggregate._addTrans', ...parameters...]);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had wondered about that approach, but wanted some confirmation before I started playing around with the code. I've implemented this now.

Comment: I am about to try this for our sites with a similar setup of a aggregate set of data, but the difference is we only have some individual sites tracking. Because of our shared setup, where by the individual sites share the common checkout page, what would happen if we added the add transaction code for the individual site even if the site didn't have analytics installed ?