# Passing Google Analytics data from classic to universal

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I need to explore the possibility of passing my existing GA eCommerce data (using Classic Analytics) over to a new universal analytics account.

I do not want to make the full switch as yet for various reasons. I do however want to [use universal analytics to track newsletter email opens](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/17/email-tracking-google-analytics/comment-page-1/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1377488480).

I would very much like to include the transaction data to this new universal analytics account so that I can put opens and revenue side-by-side. I know it is possible to [aggregate analytics accounts to one profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506816/google-analytics-ecommerce-tracking-multiple-accounts#_=_) but because classic and universal are different I wonder if there is any way we can aggregate data from Classic to universal?

Or do I place two tracking scripts on the thank you page?

Any tips or advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From official help page ["Set up Universal Analytics"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009):

> Best practices
>
> If you want to try UA on a website you’re already tracking with Google
>   Analytics, we recommend you use the ga.js and analytics.js tracking
>   code concurrently to maintain continuity in your first account. Send
>   the data sets to separate properties: UA data to a dedicated UA
>   property, and ga.js data to a non-UA property. Data cannot be merged
>   or reprocessed after it’s collected. Alternative configurations are
>   not supported and can result in corrupted or incomplete data.
>
> In the coming months, look for documentation to help you migrating
>   your existing Google Analytics web properties and data to UA.

So you can place two tracking scripts on the page.

Comment: Hi jeillica, thanks for that info, I was wondering if we could pass in a similar way to aggregating two Classic accounts. Looks like i will have to place the two codes on the site. Thanks :)